# Unable to map nested datasource field of cosmos db to a root index field of Azure indexer using REST APIs

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cognitive-search

I have a mongo db collection `users` with the following data format

```
{
    "name": "abc",
    "email": "abc@xyz.com"
    "address": {
        "city": "Gurgaon",
        "state": "Haryana"
    }
}
```

Now I'm creating a datasource, an index, and an indexer for this collection using azure rest apis.

Datasource

```
def create_datasource():
  request_body = {
      "name": 'users-datasource',
      "description": "",
      "type": "cosmosdb",
      "credentials": {
          "connectionString": "<db conenction url>"
      },
      "container": {"name": "users"},
      "dataChangeDetectionPolicy": {
          "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.HighWaterMarkChangeDetectionPolicy",
          "highWaterMarkColumnName": "_ts"
      }
  }
  resp = requests.post(url="<create-datasource-api-url>", data=json.dumps(request_body), 
    headers=headers)
```

Index for the above datasource

```
def create_index(config):

  request_body = {
      'name': "users-index",
      'fields': [
          {
              'name': 'name',
              'type': 'Edm.String'
          },
          {
              'name': 'email',
              'type': 'Edm.DateTimeOffset'
          },
          {
              'name': 'address',
              'type': 'Edm.String'
          },
          {
              'name': 'doc_id',
              'type': 'Edm.String',
              'key': True
          }
      ]
  }
  resp = requests.post(url="<azure-create-index-api-url>", data=json.dumps(request_body), 
    headers=config.headers)
```

Now the inxder for the above datasource and index

```
def create_interviews_indexer(config):
  request_body = {
    "name": "users-indexer",
    "dataSourceName": "users-datasource",
    "targetIndexName": users-index,
    "schedule": {"interval": "PT5M"},
    "fieldMappings": [
        {"sourceFieldName": "address.city", "targetFieldName": "address"},
    ]
  }
  resp = requests.post("create-indexer-pi-url", data=json.dumps(request_body), 
      headers=config.headers)
```

This creates the indexer without any exception, but when I check the  retrieved data in azure portal for the `users-indexer`, the `address` field is `null` and is not getting any value from `address.city` field mapping that is provided while creating the indexer.

I have also tried the following code as a mapping but its also not working.

```
"fieldMappings": [
        {"sourceFieldName": "/address/city", "targetFieldName": "address"},
    ]
```

The azure documentation also does not say anything about this kind of mapping. So if anyone can help me on this, it will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`container` element in data source definition allows you to specify a `query` that you can use to flatten your JSON document (Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/create-data-source) so instead of doing column mapping in the indexer definition, you can write a query and get the output in desired format.

Your code for creating data source in that case would be:

```
def create_datasource():
  request_body = {
      "name": 'users-datasource',
      "description": "",
      "type": "cosmosdb",
      "credentials": {
          "connectionString": "<db conenction url>",
      },
      "container": {
        "name": "users",
        "query": "SELECT a.name, a.email, a.address.city as address FROM a",
      },
      "dataChangeDetectionPolicy": {
          "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.HighWaterMarkChangeDetectionPolicy",
          "highWaterMarkColumnName": "_ts"
      }
  }
  resp = requests.post(url="<create-datasource-api-url>", data=json.dumps(request_body), 
    headers=headers)
```

Comment: I appreciate you efforts, but seems like the custom queries are not supported for CosmosDB. I still tried as you suggested and I got an exception while creating the indexer that is also related to the user specified queries. `Error with data source: User-specified queries are not supported for MongoDB API.  Please adjust your data source definition in order to proceed.` You can check the `create datasource` Under REST APIs section of the following link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-index-cosmosdb

Comment: Umesh...After I posted the answer I realized that you're using Mongo API instead of SQL API. My answer is not really relevant to the problem you're facing. Other answers will actually help you. Please ignore my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Support for MongoDb API flavor is in public preview - you need to explicitly indicate Mongo in the datasource's connection string as described in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-index-cosmosdb). Also note that with Mongo datasources, custom queries suggested by the previous response are not supported afaik. Hopefully someone from the team would clarify the current state of this support.

Comment: I completely missed that OP is using Mongo:).

Comment: I'm sorry but i'm unable to get your statement `you need to explicitly indicate Mongo in the datasource's connection string`. Can you please elaborate more on that?

Comment: He means that you need to specify the "apiKind" in the connection string, something like this: "AccountEndpoint=[accoundEndpoint];AccountKey=[accountKey];ApiKind=Mongodb;". It's mentioned in a subsection of the doc linked: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-index-cosmosdb#2---create-a-data-source

Answer (score 0):

It's working for me with the below field mapping correctly. Azure search query is returning values for address properly.

```
    "fieldMappings": [{"sourceFieldName": "address.city", "targetFieldName": "address"}]
```

I did made few changes to the data your provided for e.g.

1. while creating indexers, removed extra comma at the end of
   fieldmappings
2. while creating index, email field is kept at
   Edm.String and not datetimeoffset.

Please make sure you are using the Preview API version since for MongoDB API is in preview mode with Azure Search.
For e.g. https://{azure search name}.search.windows.net/indexers?api-version=**2019-05-06-Preview**

Comment: You are getting value because the target index key `address` exists in the collection. Try this `"fieldMappings": [{"sourceFieldName": "address.city", "targetFieldName": "city_name"}]` and also use `city_name` in place of `address` while creating index.
Also changing the version from `2019-05-06` to `2019-05-06-Preview` does not work

Comment: you are right. Better to raise an issue here [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-indexer-field-mappings) by commenting on article